# R studio has different version than shell

Tags: r, anaconda

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (and will upgrade very soon, yes, but have to solve this issue beforehand).

When starting R from a bash, I can see the following version:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu 
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.1                         
year           2018                        
month          07                          
day            02                          
svn rev        74947                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
nickname       Feather Spray
```

When looking at the R version from R-studio, I can see:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.4                         
year           2021                        
month          02                          
day            15                          
svn rev        80002                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
nickname       Lost Library Book
```

What do I have to do to get also version 4 in the shell?

Comment: You might get better answers by posting on super user. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out, what your R home path is in RStudio by using
`file.path(R.home("bin"),"R").` in RStudio.
For your bash use `which R` to find out which path that is using. If they differ, that is the reason for the different versions.
From there you have a couple of options:

1. Uninstall the conda-version, that will probably switch over your bash version as well.
2. Simlink the path from `which path` to the output of `file.path(R.home("bin"),"R").` That will change over your R version in bash as well.
3. If you only want to change specifically the bash behavior add `alias R=<Output of file.path(...)>` to your `.bashrc`. That will change it as well.